# How to Automate the login process of Amazon workspace in windows desktop client

Tags: windows, automation, pywinauto, amazon-workspaces

I'm using Amazon Workspace windows desktop client. Every time when I wish to start the workspace I need to login into the workspace manually. My Id and password is bit long and I want to write the script that automates this process.

> I have tried pywinauto for this purpose but since the Amazon workspace have a login form which is web form. So im not able to automate it.

Any other solution or improvement in my solution is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

It's not a completely automatic solution, but if you use a password manager many of them have an auto-fill option that will work with the Amazon WorkSpaces client.

Comment: Yeah I use that but I was looking for something that I just run a script and every thing is done its self. Thanks for your answer though